# Unable to read images simultaneously [in parallels] using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, python-imaging-library

I have 10 jpeg images in a directory.
I want to read all them simultaneously using pyspark.
I tried as follows.

```
from PIL import Image


from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf    

conf = SparkConf()
spark = SparkContext(conf=conf)       

files = glob.glob("E:\\tests\\*.jpg")

files_ = spark.parallelize(files)    

arrs = []

for fi in files_.toLocalIterator():      

    im = Image.open(fi)
    data = np.asarray(im)
    arrs.append(data)

img = np.array(arrs)    
print (img.shape)
```

The code  ended without error and printed out `img.shape`; however, it did not run in parallel.
Could you help me?

Comment: Have you tried a binary file data source (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html)?

Comment: I tried after you informed me as follows, `bds = spark.read.format("binaryFile").option("pathGlobFilter", "*.jpg").load("E:\\tests\\") print (bds)`. However, it ended with errors, `Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number`

Comment: @thunder Usually when I have this exception it's because my code doesn't see JAVA_HOME environment variable. Check if it is your case and try again

Comment: @Kafels I have installed `jdk-16.0.1_windows-x64_bin` in C:\JAVA and set it as `JAVA_HOME environment variable`.

Comment: @thunder Hmmm, to me the only version that works is the Java 8 version

Comment: @Kafels I'll try with Java 8 version

Comment: @thunder After you testing it, what is your spark version?

Comment: @Kafels The spark version is 3.1.1, Java 8 version is working, thank you.

Comment: @Kafels When trying for `spark.read.format("binaryFile")...` `AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'read'`   I used `spark = SparkContext(conf=conf)`

Comment: People commonly use `spark` to mean `SparkSession`, as in `spark=SparkSession.builder().config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()`. They also usually use `sc` for `SparkContext`.

Comment: @mazaneicha  I tried, `sc =  SparkSession.builder().config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()` but `TypeError: 'Builder' object is not callable`

Comment: damn python... :) `spark=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()` no brackets in _.builder.con..._
And then, **spark.**read.format(... not sc.read...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [rdd.map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html) to load and transform the pictures in parallel and then [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.collect.html) the rdd into a Python list:

```python
files = glob.glob("E:\\tests\\*.jpg")

file_rdd = spark.parallelize(files)

def image_to_array(path):
    im = Image.open(path)
    data = np.asarray(im)
    return data

array_rdd = file_rdd.map(lambda f: image_to_array(f))
result_list = array_rdd.collect()
```

`result_list` is now a list with 10 elements, each element is a `numpy.ndarray`.

The function `image_to_array` will be executed on different Spark executors in parallel. If you have a multi-node Spark cluster, you have to make sure that all nodes can access `E:\\tests\\`.

After collecting the arrays, processing can continue with

```python
img = np.array(result_list, dtype=object)
```

Comment: How would you start `SparkSession` or `SparkContext` for this task, I'm struggling on it...

Comment: I am using `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate().sparkContext`, but the code you have given in the question works also

Answer (score 3):

My solution follows the same idea from [werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129801/werner), but I did only using spark libs:

```py
from pyspark.ml.image import ImageSchema
import numpy as np


df = (spark
      .read
      .format("image")
      .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.jpg")
      .load("your_data_path"))

df = df.select('image.*')

# Pre-caching the required schema. If you remove this line an error will be raised.
ImageSchema.imageFields

# Transforming images to np.array
arrays = df.rdd.map(ImageSchema.toNDArray).collect()

img = np.array(arrays)
print(img.shape)
```